# Infinitely many primes of the form $pn+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math

> Prove: Given a prime $p$, there are infinitely many $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$, for   which $pn+1$ is a prime.

This is a simplified version of [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions), so is there any elementary solution to this problem?

A proof by contradiction is recommended. Just like the proof of the existence of infinitely many primes by Euclid.

Comment: There are infinitely many primes of the form $nk+1$ for a fixed $n\in\Bbb Z$ by an elementary proof [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-781-theory-of-numbers-spring-2012/lecture-notes/MIT18_781S12_lec12.pdf) (using cyclotomic polynomials). Your claim follows.

Comment: See also http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.facm/1229442627 and http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/dirichleteuclid.pdf.

Comment: Where did you get this question? It has been posted a number of times in, say, the past week.

Comment: This is a trivial consequence of the Dirichlet-Legendre-Vallée-Poussin Theorem. In fact, for large $x > 0$, the are roughly $\frac{1}{\phi(p)}\textrm{Li}(x) = \frac{1}{p-1}\textrm{Li}(x)$ such primes $\le x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All prime divisors of $\frac{(pr)^{p}-1}{pr-1}$ for any positive integer $r$ are of the form $pk+1$ (proof below).

Now assume for contradiction there are finitely many primes $\{p_1,p_2,\ldots, p_t\}$ of the form $pk+1$. Let $r=p_1p_2\cdots p_t$.

Then all prime divisors of $\frac{(pr)^{p}-1}{pr-1}$ are of the form $pk
+1$ and coprime to $p_1,p_2,\ldots, p_t$. Contradiction.

---

Proof: Define $\text{ord}_n(a)$ to be the least positive integer $m$ such that $a^m\equiv 1\pmod{n}$.

Lemma: if $x^t\equiv 1\pmod{n}$, then $\text{ord}_n(x)\mid t$. Proof: if $t=\text{ord}_n(x)l+r,\, 0<r<\text{ord}_n(x)$, then $1\equiv x^t\equiv \left(x^{\text{ord}_n(x)}\right)^lx^r\equiv x^r\pmod{n}$, contradiction. q.e.d.

Let $q$ be a prime divisor of $\frac{(pr)^{p}-1}{pr-1}$. Then $\text{ord}_q(pr)\in\{1,p\}$ and $\gcd(q,pr)=1$. For contradiction, assume $q\mid pr-1$.

$$q\mid (pr)^{p-1}+(pr)^{p-2}+\cdots+1\equiv 1^{p-1}+1^{p-2}+\cdots + 1\equiv p\not\equiv 0\pmod{q},$$

contradiction. Therefore $\text{ord}_q(pr)=p$, so by Fermat's Little Theorem and the lemma $p\mid q-1$. Q.E.D